# Issues when sorting a polars DataFrame based on a Categorical column

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, sorting, python-polars

I am quite new `polars`, and while messing around with grouping and sorting operations, I found that sorting a polars DataFrame based on a *created* `Categorical` column results in weird behaviors.

Specifically, given a polars DataFrame `df` containing a categorical column `decile` that is created via the `.qcut()` method with values ('q1', 'q2', ..., 'q10'), directly applying the following: `df.sort('decile')` correctly sorts the data.

However, if we were to group the DataFrame based on the `decile` column **first**, and then sort it based on `decile`, the resulting DataFrame doesn't sort properly!

The weird thing is that if you were to sort the DataFrame based on another column **before** creating the `decile` column, sorting the `decile` column now works *even after grouping* by it; though the sorting order is reversed (i.e., ascending sorts descending and vice-versa, which is weird).

Here's a minimal reproducible example to illustrate the case:

```
# Create a toy DataFrame
size = 1e5
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "id": np.random.randint(50000, size=int(size), dtype=np.uint16),
    "amount": np.round(np.random.uniform(10, 100000, int(size)).astype(np.float32), 2),
    "quantity": np.random.randint(1, 7, size=int(size), dtype=np.uint16)
})
```

Illustrating the first case:

```
df = (df.groupby("id")
      .agg(revenue=pl.sum("amount"), tot_quantity=pl.sum("quantity"))
     )
df = df.with_columns(
    (df["revenue"].qcut(10, labels=[f'q{i}' for i in range(10, 0, -1)])).alias("decile")
)
df = df.groupby("decile").agg(pl.col("revenue").sum(), pl.col("tot_quantity").sum())
df = df.sort('decile')  # This doesn't work properly!
```

However, sorting based on `revenue` first, fixes the problem, but the sorting order is reversed:

```
df = (df.groupby("id")
      .agg(revenue=pl.sum("amount"), tot_quantity=pl.sum("quantity"))
     ).sort("revenue")  # Sort by "revenue" prior to creating "decile"
df = df.with_columns(
    (df["revenue"].qcut(10, labels=[f'q{i}' for i in range(10, 0, -1)])).alias("decile")
)
df = df.groupby("decile").agg(pl.col("revenue").sum(), pl.col("tot_quantity").sum())
df = df.sort('decile')  # It works now but order is reversed!
```

Anyone has any idea what's going on? I've been trying to figure out why this is happening but to no avail, I tried casting to a different datatype but still did't work.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the sorted order of `pl.Categorical` columns is done by its underlying physical representation. Use [`cat.set_ordering('lexical')`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.cat.set_ordering.html):

```py
(df["revenue"].qcut(10, labels=[f'q{i:02d}' for i in range(10, 0, -1)])).cat.set_ordering('lexical').alias("decile")
```

```py
shape: (10, 3)
┌────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┐
│ decile ┆ revenue      ┆ tot_quantity │
│ ---    ┆ ---          ┆ ---          │
│ cat    ┆ f32          ┆ i64          │
╞════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╡
│ q01    ┆ 1.1978e9     ┆ 68797        │
│ q02    ┆ 8.43843712e8 ┆ 51888        │
│ q03    ┆ 6.91437504e8 ┆ 43693        │
│ q04    ┆ 5.75548224e8 ┆ 39623        │
│ q05    ┆ 4.72274336e8 ┆ 35500        │
│ q06    ┆ 3.960448e8   ┆ 26126        │
│ q07    ┆ 3.3030432e8  ┆ 24030        │
│ q08    ┆ 2.56758752e8 ┆ 22728        │
│ q09    ┆ 1.69156608e8 ┆ 20269        │
│ q10    ┆ 6.3238428e7  ┆ 17518        │
└────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┘
```

(Note how I formatted `i` with `02d` to get a padded 0 in, so `q10` is sorted last.)