# Sort by categorical data in polars, string that starts with numerical

Tags: python, python-polars

Sample of display

```
| 2-Informa localizacao e CPF     ┆ 229889           │
│ 1-Onboarding + Escolhe Segmento ┆ 383133           │
│ 6-Define metodo de pagamento    ┆ 37520            │
│ 3-Escolhe plano                 ┆ 95487            │
│ 4-Realiza cadastro              ┆ 46027            │
```

Sample for testing

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"Steps":["2-Informa localizacao e CPF","1-Onboarding + Escolhe Segmento","6-Define metodo de pagamento"],"UserIds":[229889,383133,37520]},schema_overrides={"Steps":pl.Categorical,"UserIds":pl.UInt32})
```

I have the following dataframe, in polars

Is there a easy way to sort that categorical data so the string that starts with the value one would be the first row,2 the second and so on is worth noting that the numerical columns are are not always in a perfect descending order.

Comment: See [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76984356/issues-when-sorting-a-polars-dataframe-based-on-a-categorical-column).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to:

- cast to string
- [split the string into 2 parts](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.splitn.html#polars.Expr.str.splitn)
- extract the first part with indexing: `.struct[0]`
- cast to `int` for a numerical sort

```py
df = pl.from_repr("""
┌─────────────────────────────────┬─────────┐
│ Steps                           ┆ UserIds │
│ ---                             ┆ ---     │
│ cat                             ┆ i64     │
╞═════════════════════════════════╪═════════╡
│ 2-Informa localizacao e CPF     ┆ 229889  │
│ 1-Onboarding + Escolhe Segmento ┆ 383133  │
│ 6-Define metodo de pagamento    ┆ 37520   │
│ 10-Omg Hello                    ┆ 12345   │
│ 3-Escolhe plano                 ┆ 95487   │
│ 4-Realiza cadastro              ┆ 46027   │
└─────────────────────────────────┴─────────┘
""")

df.sort(
   pl.col("Steps").cast(str).str.splitn("-", 2).struct[0].cast(int)
)
```

```py
shape: (6, 2)
┌─────────────────────────────────┬─────────┐
│ Steps                           ┆ UserIds │
│ ---                             ┆ ---     │
│ cat                             ┆ i64     │
╞═════════════════════════════════╪═════════╡
│ 1-Onboarding + Escolhe Segmento ┆ 383133  │
│ 2-Informa localizacao e CPF     ┆ 229889  │
│ 3-Escolhe plano                 ┆ 95487   │
│ 4-Realiza cadastro              ┆ 46027   │
│ 6-Define metodo de pagamento    ┆ 37520   │
│ 10-Omg Hello                    ┆ 12345   │
└─────────────────────────────────┴─────────┘
```

Comment: You're probably right that they have double digit numbers and they want 10 after 9 instead of before 2.

Comment: Fascinating and that doesnt even overwrite the original column value, starting to like this library

Answer (score 1):

The `sort` method accepts expressions so you can have it sort by the Utf8 version of your Steps column like this:

```
df.sort(pl.col("Steps").cast(pl.Utf8()))
```

This doesn't change the index that represents each string value, it just changes the sort order of the df itself.